# I need to align tables with equal sizes (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make 2 Tables with vertical alignment.

so I made 2 div which one is "col-lg-10", another one is "col-lg-5"

I think it works with 1-Table and Half-Table exactly

but it doesn't work exactly, it's a little bit different.

[col-lg-10 / col-lg-5] , I think 10 is exactly half value of 5....

why doesn't it work?

```
<div class="table-responsive col-lg-10">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-1">ABC</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">DEF</td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" style="word-break:break-all">FGGFGGFGGFGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGG</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">342</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">ABc</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">DDF</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">AvV</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">DXZ</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">QQW</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive col-lg-5">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-2">ABC</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3">DEF</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Result ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn1sQ.png)

Comment: Your columns need to be in row elements.

Comment: remove the gutter from the right of cols-lg-5: 
`.table-responsive.col-lg-5 {padding-right:0;}` https://www.bootply.com/gSfrG4Ye2C

Comment: Also, column classes are not a generic sizing utility. They're meant to be used with other grid classes. Like the previously mentioned `.row` class and the fact they have gutters (padding) like @Pete mentioned. They are not meant to size table columns and tables (at least the way you're expecting). Column sizes are for columns and they have a gutter.

Comment: thanks guys, your comments are so useful, thx very much!!

Answer (score 0):

[check the image this is regarding col*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zggP8.png)

here is the code after correction you can change the offset value as we want

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-md-10 offset-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr class=row>
            <td class="col-lg-1">ABC</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">DEF</td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" style="word-break:break-all">FGGFGGFGGFGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGFGGG</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">342</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">ABc</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">DDF</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">AvV</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">DXZ</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">QQW</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">QQW</td>
            <td class="col-lg-1">QQW</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 offset-sm-4 ">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-2">ABC</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3">DEF</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```